# Where to get a list of all JavaFX CSS properties names?

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I am trying to build a [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/index.html) mode file in order to provide correct syntax highlighting and completion help for the JavaFX flavour of CSS, based on the original CSS mode.

In [JavaFX CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), most properties are the same as in classic CSS, but some don't exist, some are different, and ALL properties are prefixed with `-fx-`

So, for example,

```
width: 600px;
```

becomes

```
-fx-width: 600px;
```

**Where could I obtain a list, in plain text, of all the existing JavaFX CSS properties names**, so that I could replace the normal CSS properties name in the JavaScript mode file ?

Note : if such a mode file for CodeMirror already exists, it would be even better, of course. But Google didn't help there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default styles for all javafx css properties are defined (in JavaFX8) in a file called modena.css. I wrote a python script to extract every property listed and write them to a text file, resulting in the following output:

https://wheelercode.wordpress.com/javafx-css-properties-selectors-list/

Answer (score 3):

The best ressources I know is the JavaFX CSS Reference Guide of Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

I am not sure there is everything but the list is pretty long.
It is not plain text but you can manage to obtain a plain text list from this document. 
(In the source code of the webpage all css properties are label with class="propertyname")

Comment: Thanks. I liked to this doc in my question. I actually was hoping for something better, like a plain list with just the property names. Anyway good idea with the css selector, I might try it. Any suggestion how to extract the names using the css class of the labels ?

Comment: I never did it before but a simple program should work.
Probably just looking for the what comes after 
<td class="propertyname"> until you don't find a </td>
Can't help more on this point.
Publish the list if you get it. This will help other people !

Comment: I'll see, if I get to do it I'll publish the list and the CodeMirror mode file.